# Realm.IO - How to parse JSONArray using createOrUpdateAllFromJson?

Tags: android, json, realm, realm-list

I am facing issue with parsing in JSONArray using createOrUpdateAllFromJson. 
The code is as follows:

```
JSON response:
    {
      "recipe": {
        "_id": "56387b241a258f0300c469ac",
    "cookingSteps": [
          "Sätt ugnen på 175 grader.",
          "Lägg kycklingfiléerna i en ugnsfast form. \r\nBlanda ihop ingredienserna till såsen och häll sedan över kycklingen.",
          "Laga i mitten av ugnen i ca. 60 min.\r\n\r\nFantastiskt enkelt och gott:)"
        ]
    }
    }
```

My RecipeRealmObject class:

```
public class RecipeRealmObject extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String _id;
    private RealmList<RealmString> cookingSteps;

 public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
public RealmList<RealmString> getCookingSteps() {
        return cookingSteps;
    }

    public void setCookingSteps(RealmList<RealmString> cookingSteps) {
        this.cookingSteps = cookingSteps;
    }
}
```

RealmString class:

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {

    private String string;

    public RealmString() {
    }

    public RealmString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }


}
```

Parsing JSON using createOrUpdateAllFromJson method:

```
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(RecipeRealmObject.class, json);
```

But I am getting the following exception while trying to parse the response:

Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value Sätt ugnen på knappt 225 grader. Smörj en ugnsfast form som ska vara så liten att fiskblocket ligger trångt och ha kanter som går minst någon cm över fiskens höjd. at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Nope that won't work because `RealmString` is an object while `String` is not. You'll need to parse the JSON manually with GSON or equivalent

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If I will parse the JSON manually with GSON or equivalent  then  I won't able to avail the feature of createOrUpdateAllFromJson(RecipeRealmObject.class, json) method.

Comment: use another method realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(RecipeRealmObject.class, json);

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method from Realm in which you can pass Json String JSONObject and inputstream as well

```
    realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(modelclass.class,Jsonstring);
    realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(modelclass.class,JSONObject);
    realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(modelclass.class,InputStream);
```